# How to replace all occurences of specific words with given replacements in a given string in PHP

Tags: php

I want users to write HTML in disguise and so to write a link, they just have to write the following:

```
#link webpage.php #linktoken #linktext Click here linktext# link#
```

This will be equivalent to writing the following HTML:

```
<a href="webpage.php">Click here</a>
```

- Here `#link` will be changed to `<a href="`
- `#linktoken` will be changed to `">`
- `#linktext` and `linktext#` will be changed to `""`
- `link#` will be changed to `</a>`
- the text between `#link` and `#linktoken` will be preserved

This will leave us with the following:

```
<a href=" webpage.php ">Click here</a>
```

And lastly I want to remove the spaces before and after the word "webpage.php". This will leave me with the desired result:

```
<a href="webpage.php">Click here</a>
```

Any solution?

Comment: I'll try to avoid asking "why". What have you tried? Have you tried [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) or [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). Both of which would be a suitable solution (preg_replace() could be 'better'). What issues are you having with it?

Comment: use `trim(str)` to remove the whitespaces

Comment: This is a bad closure.  How can it Need Debugging Details if there is no code to be broken.  I've voted to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

First, I will say I am cringing at the experience this will offer your users.  What user would want to go through this convolution just to enter a hyperlink?

Beyond that gripe, Here are three ways to do it:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c174dada6d36966aa54a808bc1c588a047916070))

```
$translations=['#link '=>'<a href="',' #linktoken'=>'">',' #linktext '=>'',' linktext#'=>'',' link#'=>'</a>'];
$string='Here is a test: #link webpage1.php #linktoken #linktext Click here 1 linktext# link# and a second: #link webpage2.php #linktoken #linktext Click here 2 linktext# link#';
echo strtr($string,$translations);
echo "\n\n";
echo str_replace(array_keys($translations),$translations,$string);
echo "\n\n";
echo preg_replace('/#link (.*?) #linktoken #linktext (.*?) linktext# link#/','<a href="$1">$2</a>',$string);
```

Output:

```
Here is a test: <a href="webpage1.php">Click here 1</a> and a second: <a href="webpage2.php">Click here 2</a>

Here is a test: <a href="webpage1.php">Click here 1</a> and a second: <a href="webpage2.php">Click here 2</a>

Here is a test: <a href="webpage1.php">Click here 1</a> and a second: <a href="webpage2.php">Click here 2</a>
```

Comment: If I say thank you @mickmackusa, its still understatement. This does exactly what i want. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to split the `string` into an `array` by `" "`. `For each` item in your `array`, you will need to check whether that's a keyword and if so, `trim` it and replace it with the correspondent replacement.

**1. Splitting:**

```
$strArray = explode(" ", $input);
```

**2. Check for keywords:**

```
$output = "";
foreach ($strArray as $key => $value) {
    if ((strpos($value, "#") !== false) && (strpos($value, "link") !== false)) {
        $val = trim($value);
        if ($val === "#link") $output .= '<a href="';
        else if ($val === "#linktoken") $output .= ">";
        else if (($val === "#linktext") || ($val === "linktext#")) $output .= "";
        else if ($val === "link#") $output .= "</a>";
    } else {
        $output .= ((strlen($output) === 0) ? " " : "") . $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you too @Lajos Arpad for your assistance, however, the last code line gives the following error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in ... on line .... Please can you fix that.

Comment: @smacaz thank you for pointing it out, it was a typo, I have written $strlen instead of strlen. I have edited my answer to fix that problem.